# Woocommerce: add free product if cart has 3 items

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

What I'm trying to do is to add free product if user have 3 product in cart.
I choosed `woocommerce_add_cart_item` hook for this.
Here is my code :

```
add_filter('woocommerce_add_cart_item', 'set_item_as_free', 99, 1);

function set_item_as_free($cart_item) {

    global $woocommerce;
    $products_with_price = 0;

    foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
        if($values['data']->price == 0) {
            continue; 
        } else {
            $products_with_price++;
        }
    }

    if( $products_with_price > 1 && $products_with_price % 3 == 1) {
        $cart_item['data']->set_price(0);
        return $cart_item;
    }
    return $cart_item;

}
```

I also tried `$cart_item['data']->price = 0;` but it doesn't work out either :(
Is there is something I do wrong or maybe there is some other way to get this done?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you figured out the problem? I'm having the same task and don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this modified code: (Have changed the condition.)

```
add_filter('woocommerce_add_cart_item', 'set_item_as_free', 99, 1);

function set_item_as_free($cart_item) {

    global $woocommerce;
    $products_with_price = 0;

    foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
        if($values['data']->price == 0) {
            continue; 
        } else {
            $products_with_price++;
        }
    }

    if( $products_with_price >= 3 && $products_with_price % 3 == 1) {
        $cart_item['data']->set_price(0);
        return $cart_item;
    }
    return $cart_item;

}
```

If you don't want to add a free product again after a user purchases another 3 products above the existing cart then remove " `&& $products_with_price % 3 == 1`" from the last condition.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the `woocommerce_add_cart_item` hook to set the price of the product, a lot of plugin like to refetch the price of the product in the database in the hook `woocommerce_before_calculate_totals` (that's the case of WPML/WCML)

So instead use this hook

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', function ( $cart_obj ) {

    // This is necessary for WC 3.0+
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Avoiding hook repetition (when using price calculations for example)
    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 ) {
        return;
    }


    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( $cart_obj->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        if ( isset( $cart_item['free_item'] ) ) {
            $cart_item['data']->set_price( 0 );
        }
    }
} );
```